# 2023: год в модерации

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, статистика, итоги-года

Снова настал этот момент года! У нас есть [традиция](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%5D+%5B%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%5D+is%3Aquestion), прощаясь с прошлым и встречая новый год, делиться статистикой модерации за предыдущий год.

Как, возможно, известно большинству из вас, сайты сообщества Stack Exchange модерируются несколько иначе, чем другие сайты в Интернете:

> Мы разработали сетевой движок Stack Exchange так, чтобы он был в основном саморегулирующимся, поскольку мы компенсируем общую стоимость модерации системы за счет тысяч крошечных кусочков усилий, вносимых обычными повседневными пользователями.
> -- [Теория Модерации](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Это не устраняет необходимости в наличии [модераторов](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) в целом, но это значит, что основная часть модерации выполняется обычными людьми — как вы. Каждая частица времени и усилий, которые вы вкладываете в сайт, дает вам доступ к большему количеству привилегий, которые вы можете использовать, чтобы помочь в этой работе, и все это дает совокупный эффект, который имеет большое значение для обеспечения того, чтобы сайты Stack Exchange оставались ценным источником высококачественного контента в Интернете.

Итак, пока мы прощаемся с 2023 годом (и январем 2024-го...) и погружаемся в 2024, давайте оглянемся назад на то, чего мы достигли как сообщество... взглянув на некоторую [*захватывающую* статистику](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmN7M.gif). Ниже приведена разбивка действий по модерации, выполненных в Stack Overflow на русском за последние 12 месяцев:

| Действие | Модераторы | Дух сообщества¹ | Сообщество² |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Все комментарии к публикации перенесенные в чат | 151 | 0 | 0 |
| Обработаны тревоги ответов | 4,879 | 2,018 | 0 |
| Ответы отмечены тревогами | 64 | 2,915 | 3,911 |
| Награды отменены | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Обработаны тревоги комментариев | 1,063 | 433 | 42 |
| Комментарии удалены⁸ | 4,885 | 273 | 10,068 |
| Комментарии отмечены тревогами | 115 | 37 | 1,380 |
| Комментарии восстановлены | 55 | 0 | 0 |
| Расширение в команды Менеджера Сообщества | 30 | 0 | 0 |
| Публикации созданы | 0 | 8,215 | 0 |
| Публикации удалены⁷ | 2,112 | 19,928 | 9,535 |
| Публикации заблокированы | 28 | 151 | 0 |
| Публикации восстановлены | 34 | 1 | 856 |
| Публикации разблокированы | 4 | 18 | 0 |
| Обработаны тревоги вопросов⁶ | 1,241 | 4,954 | 971 |
| Вопросы закрыты | 1,275 | 5,468 | 512 |
| Вопросы отмечены тревогами⁶ | 91 | 236 | 6,960 |
| Вопросы объединены | 8 | 0 | 0 |
| Вопросы перенесены | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| Вопросы защищены | 8 | 26 | 295 |
| Вопросы повторно открыты | 72 | 57 | 14 |
| Отменена защита вопросов | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| Редакции отредактированы | 18 | 0 | 0 |
| Метки подсветки языка заданы | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Синонимы меток созданы | 128 | 1 | 0 |
| Синонимы меток предложены | 112 | 0 | 2 |
| Метки объединены | 106 | 0 | 0 |
| Рассмотрены задачи⁵: Очередь "Голоса за закрытие" | 45 | 0 | 25,469 |
| Рассмотрены задачи⁵: Очередь "Первые ответы" | 1 | 0 | 14,494 |
| Рассмотрены задачи⁵: Очередь "Первые вопросы" | 6 | 11 | 25,845 |
| Рассмотрены задачи⁵: Очередь "Запоздалые ответы" | 1 | 0 | 7,652 |
| Рассмотрены задачи⁵: Очередь "Сообщения низкого качества" | 29 | 16 | 26,783 |
| Рассмотрены задачи⁵: Очередь "Голоса за переоткрытие" | 20 | 0 | 4,274 |
| Рассмотрены задачи⁵: Очередь "Предлагаемые правки" | 56 | 740 | 14,038 |
| Пользователи забаненные на просмотр | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Досрочно снятые баны на просмотр | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Досрочно снятые блокировки пользователей | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Связались пользователи | 155 | 0 | 0 |
| Удалено пользователей | 78 | 0 | 0 |
| Уничтожено пользователей⁴ | 55 | 0 | 0 |
| Заблокированно пользователей³ | 86 | 34 | 0 |

#### Примечания

¹ Это относится к автоматизированной системе, также известной как [user #-1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1)..

² «Сообщество» здесь относится как к [членству в Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users), так и к *без* [ромбам рядом с их именами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators).

³ Система приостанавливает действия пользователей в трех случаях: когда пользователь создается повторно после того, как он был ранее заблокирован, когда пользователь создается повторно после того, как он был уничтожен за спам или злоупотребления, и когда в отношении учетной записи действует общесетевая блокировка.

⁴ "Уничтоженный" пользователь удаляется вместе со всем, что он разместил: вопросы, ответы, комментарии. [Обычно используется как целесообразный способ избавиться от спама.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁵ При этом учитывается каждый отправленный (не пропущенный) отзыв, поэтому 2 предлагаемых отзыва об изменениях, необходимых для утверждения изменения, будут считаться как 2, цель состоит в том, чтобы указать частоту действий модерации. Это также относится к тревогам и т.п.

⁶ Включает в себя тревоги закрытия (но *не* закрытие или повторное открытие голосования). Сообщество может обрабатывать эти тревоги, если хотя бы один человек проголосует за закрытие вопроса с пометкой закрытия.

⁷ Игнорируются многочисленные удаления, которые происходят автоматически в ответ на какое-то другое действие.

⁸ Сюда входят комментарии, удаленные их собственными авторами (которые также учитывают некоторое количество обработанных тревог комментариев).

#### Для дальнейшего чтения:

- Вы также можете посмотреть [этот отсчёт на других сайтах](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222023%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Или посмотреть [подробную информацию о количестве закрытых и переоткрытых вопросов по всем сайтам](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396299/208518)

Желаем всем счастливого 2024 года! ^_^

Comment: 151 posts or comments? I expect posts.

Comment: @Qwertiy i guess that's per action not per comment.

Comment: What does mean "bounties canceled"? I thought they are irrevocable.

Comment: @Глеб moderators can do much more than regular users

Comment: What does mean *Tag highlight language set* / *Метки подсветки языка заданы*?

Comment: @Глеб, модераторы могут отменять награды, но используется крайне редко.

Comment: @wchistow настроен язык подсветки синтаксиса для вопросов/ответов с меткой. Например, открываем https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info, крутим в самый низ, видим надпись: `Язык кода (используется для выделения синтаксиса): lang-py`